# SQL for last six "full" months

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table containing one datetime column. I need to return rows for only last 6 months. This can be done by

```
WHERE CloseTime >= DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, - 6, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)), 0)
```

This gets me data for the month I am starting this script + 6 last months. So e.g. if I run this script today, Ill get the data for this month + all previous months till April (04).

Now I need to modify the condition so if I run the script today, the data will be obtained only for months 03-09 only, exluding days in this month (10).

Any advice, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to have the previous 6 months regardless of whether today is the 1st, 3rd, 9th, 29th, whatever, then just subtract 7 months. Here is one way to do that: get the first of the month into a variable, then use an open-ended range in the query.

```
DECLARE @ThisMonth DATETIME;
SET @ThisMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101');

SELECT...
WHERE CloseTime >= DATEADD(MONTH, -7, @ThisMonth)
  AND CloseTime <  @ThisMonth;
```

You could also use `0` in place of `'19000101'` but I prefer an explicit date than implicit shorthand (it was a very tough habit to break).

If you really don't like variables, then you can make the query a lot more complex by repeating the expression to calculate the first of this month (and in the start of the range, subtract 7 from the number of months):

```
SELECT...
WHERE CloseTime >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE())-7, '19000101')
  AND CloseTime <  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', GETDATE()), '19000101');
```

Yuck. Variables make this much tidier.

Comment: Btw is there any option how to solve this issue without using variables?

Comment: @DNac yes but what is your opposition to variables?

Comment: I am creating "Views" where each view embodies one report. I'd prefer avoiding using variables in views. But it's only "cosmetic" thing.

Answer (score 1):

When creating queries you do not want to use a function on the search column since it will result in a full table scan.

The solution works and should pick up any index on CloseTime.

```
-- Get me data in months 3 (mar) to 9 (sep) of this year
select 
    *
from 
    my_table 
where 
    CloseTime between 
    DATEADD(d, -1, '03-01-2013') and DATEADD(d, +1, '09-20-2013')
```

If the table is small and a full table scan is not a issue, a simple solution is to use the MONTH function.

```
-- Get me data in months 3 (mar) to 9 (sep) of this year
select 
    *
from 
    my_table 
where 
    MONTH(CloseTime) IN (3,4,5,6,7,8,9) and YEAR(CloseTime) = 2013
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. However I can't use specified dates as this needs to by dynamic solution.

Comment: [What do the devil and between have in common](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), is very much worth a read. Using culture specific date formats is another to avoid (is `03-01-2013` 1st March or 3rd Jan?), I think this is covered in [Mishandling date/range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries). Both articles well worth a read and courtesy of [Aaron Bertrand](http://stackoverflow.com/users/61305/aaron-bertrand).

Comment: Finally, if you are hard coding dates why bother using DATEADD? e.g. instead of `DATEADD(d, +1, '09-20-2013')` why not just write `09-21-2013` (aside from the fact it should be the culture invariant `20130921`).

Comment: If I am writing a quick query to pull data for a cultural specific database, why not use literals?  Yeah, I could use a date instead of string literal.  If the user is looking for the past 6 months, not including this month, a piece of code to place in a automated job, go with Aaron's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at Aaron's article.  Its a very good read.

I wondered if there was some new function that was not tested since that article.

If you are using 2012, why not use the format function?  Logically, you want date variables with a 01 day.  The query plan still gets a clustered index scan.

Let's see how this solution stacks up using Aaron's test database.

```
-- Use the sample
use [DateTesting]
go

-- Johns - log by 6 months
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Johns_LogBy6Months
   @date SMALLDATETIME
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @cmp_date SMALLDATETIME = format(@date, 'yyyyMM01');
   DECLARE @c INT;

   SELECT @c = COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.SomeLogTable
        WHERE DateColumn >= dateadd(m, -7, @cmp_date) 
        AND DateColumn < @cmp_date
END
GO

-- Aarons - log by 6 months
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Aarons_LogBy6Months
   @date SMALLDATETIME
AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @c INT;
   DECLARE @cmp_date SMALLDATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19000101', @date), '19000101');

   SELECT @c = COUNT(*)
        FROM dbo.SomeLogTable
        WHERE 
        DateColumn >=  dateadd(m, -7, @cmp_date) 
        AND DateColumn <  @cmp_date
END
GO
```

Lets make 1000 calls to the functions.

```
-- Sample calls x 1000  
PRINT CONVERT(char(23), GETDATE(), 121);
GO

EXEC dbo.Johns_LogCountByDay @date = '20091005';
GO 1000

PRINT CONVERT(char(23), GETDATE(), 121);
GO

EXEC dbo.Aarons_LogBy6Months @date = '20091005';
GO 1000

PRINT CONVERT(char(23), GETDATE(), 121);
GO
```

Here are the executions times.

```
2013-10-10 11:58:49.547

Beginning execution loop
Batch execution completed 1000 times.

2013-10-10 11:58:52.837

Beginning execution loop
Batch execution completed 1000 times.

2013-10-10 11:58:55.883
```

In summary a call to the new format() function and a implicit cast to a small date time takes a little more time than a dateadd() and datediff() with two string (date) literals.

The format() solution seems more intuitive or self documenting to me.  The time difference was 3.3 versus 3.0 sec.

I have to give the speed test a win to Aaron's solution.  Stick with in-equality comparisons of date variables.  They are faster.

In short, I will have to fix my bad habits.

Comment: Format() also has quite expensive CLR overhead. When you do it just once it's not terrible (except on first invocation since the service started), but if you do it in the SELECT list etc. the impact can be huge. See http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/Posts/17608/different-ways-to-remove-time-part-from-datetime-values-faster-methods.aspx

Comment: I also did [some performance testing here](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-trim-time-from-datetime) but knew not to even bother including `FORMAT()` as a contender - would have skewed all my graphs I think.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar request. I needed last six months and next six months of appointments. But just like you I needed the full months. So a simple getdate +- 180 wouldn't do.

I took a more simple approach. I get the year and month and turn it into a number like 201912. Then do a between clause. Its dynamic and I get full months.

I'm sure there's more sophisticated approaches, but this is what I came up with.

```
WHERE Year([ApptDate])*100 + Month([ApptDate]) between Year(getdate()-180)*100 + Month(getdate()-180) and Year(getdate()+180)*100 + Month(getdate()+180)
```